# Javascript/jQuery - apply CSS style to class element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to insert CSS style to a h1 class element. It worked before i updated mmy theme, but for some reason it doesnt work now. Anyone know why?

I've tried getElementsByClassName and [0] to find arrays, nothing is working for me.
The CSS class has display:none, because i want the title to only show on pages that contains the class "product_title entry-title". So when it find that class, it should put a CSS class to the element to display:block, so that it will show on those pages.

```js
z=document.querySelector("product_title entry-title");
 z.style.display="block";
```

```css
#content h1:first-child {
    padding-top: 0px;
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="product_title entry-title">Arkham Horror</h1>
```

Comment: ops, be aware. the duplicate line of "document" is a simple copy paste error.

Comment: Then do the edits please, since that's throwing an error in your snippet, also your selector has to be like this: `querySelector('.product_title.entry-title')`

Comment: Thanks, but i still end up getting this error. Even though i tried all the comments on this thread :( 

"(index):434 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at (index):434"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing dot `.` while selecting the element using querySelector.Dot `.` is required to select the element using it's class.

Also one class will be enough to select the element

```js
var z = document.querySelector(".product_title");
z.style.display = "block";
```

```css
#content h1:first-child {
  padding-top: 0px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section id='content'>
<h1 class="product_title entry-title">Arkham Horror</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: He needs both classes to be present on the element in order to show them

Comment: Thanks, but i still end up getting this error. Even though i tried all the comments on this thread :( 

"(index):434 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at (index):434"

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variable first. Also, querySelectorAll works the same way as CSS selectors so you'll need to add dots to your classes for querySelector to find them.

```
 var z = document.querySelector(".product_title.entry-title");
 z.style.display="block";
```

Bear in mind this will select only the first H1 with those classes so your :first-child is a bit overkill here.

Comment: Note that for elements with more than one class there should not be any whitespace in between the class names: `.product_title.entry-title`

Comment: op posted their markup. `querySelector(".product_title .entry-title");` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood the use of the `querySelector` method. Instead of just listing the classes of the desired element all delimited by a space, each class name must be preceded by a full stop `.` and if your desired element has more than one class, the classes should not have whitespace inbetween them. See the corrected code snippet:

```js
var z=document.querySelector(".product_title.entry-title");
z.style.display="block";
```

```css
h1 {
    padding-top: 0px;
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="product_title entry-title">Arkham Horror</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i still end up getting this error. Even though i tried all the comments on this thread :( 

"(index):434 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at (index):434"

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery .css() method for changing css properties. It will apply to all elements which were chosen by selector (in this case it is 'h1')
If you want to change only one element add .first()

```js
$('h1').first().css("color", "red");
$('h1').css("display", "block");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<h1>Title</h1>
```

Comment: OP didn't say they wanted to change all elements. In fact, they said they were using `[0]` with `getElementsByClassName`, which means they're just looking for the first element. And why would you include jquery to do something so simple? they just have a syntax error in the `querySelector()` selector.

Comment: Thanks, but i still end up getting this error. Even though i tried all the comments on this thread :( 

"(index):434 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at (index):434"